# "Stuttering" StartMenu for Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I've been working on and off on a text-based adventure game for a few years now. It originally started as a way to learn Python, then I moved on to projects more relevant to my career after I became comfortable with the language. I'm now somewhat competent (Still a noob, but you know, progress) and I'd like to go back to the game to add in more complex functionality.

One thing that is annoying me is a visual bug in my start menu. Below is the code:

```
import pygame
from pygame_functions import setBackgroundImage
import gamefile

pygame.init()

display_width = 1500
display_height = 750
startMenu = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("The Woodsman's Tale")


black = (0, 0, 0)
green = (0, 200, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
dark_red = (200, 0, 0)
bright_green = (0, 255, 0)
leaf_green = (0, 175, 75)
brown = (102, 51, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)


clock = pygame.time.Clock()


def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def button(msg, x, y, w, h, ic, ac, action=None):

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y + h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(startMenu, ac, (x, y, w, h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action is not None:
            if action == 'play':
                gamefile.rungame()
                start_menu().intro = False
            elif action == 'quit':
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(startMenu, ic, (x, y, w, h))

    smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 20)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    TextRect.center = (x + (w / 2), (y + (h / 2)))
    startMenu.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)


def start_menu():

    intro = True

    while intro:
        setBackgroundImage('startScreen.png')
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        largeText = pygame.font.Font('BRADHITC.ttf', 90)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("The Woodsman's Tale", largeText)
        TextRect.center = (display_width / 2, display_height / 3)
        startMenu.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button('Play', 350, 500, 200, 150, green, leaf_green, 'play')
        button('Quit', 850, 500, 200, 150, dark_red, red, 'quit')

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_menu()
```

The setbackgroundimage function being imported is this:

```
def setBackgroundImage(img):
    global bgSurface, backgroundImage
    surf = loadImage(img)
    backgroundImage = surf
    screen.blit(surf, [0, 0])
    bgSurface = screen.copy()
    updateDisplay()
```

Now, the start menu works great. Everything functions properly. My issue is that when I click on the title bar, for example to move the window, the start menu begins stuttering visually.

Exactly what is happening is this: Once I click on the title bar, the "buttons" of the start menu and the Title text of the game disappear. Once the click is released, the buttons and Title text reappear, but stutter rapidly.

I'm not really sure if I'm providing enough for anyone to be able to tell what's going wrong, so I apologize if that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fist issue is that `setBackgroundImage` seems to update the display (`updateDisplay()`).
The display has to be updated once at the end of the main application loop, and should not be updated multiple times. That cause the flickering. Remove the display update from `setBackgroundImage`:

```
def start_menu():

    intro = True

    while intro:
        setBackgroundImage('startScreen.png') # draw background but do no update the display

        # [...]

        pygame.display.update() # the one and only update at the end of the loop
        clock.tick(15)
```

---

The second issue, that the background image is loaded in `setBackgroundImage`. That cause that the image is loaded continuously in every frame. That causes a performance impact.
Load the image before the main loop and pass the `Surface` object to `setBackgroundImage`:

```py
def start_menu():

    surf = loadImage('startScreen.png')

    intro = True
    while intro:
        setBackgroundImage(surf)

        # [...]
```